# Distributing Set Intersections Over an Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was working through some examples, and found this to be true:

$(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C $

$(A \cap B) \cap(A \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$

$(A \cap B) \cap(A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$

Is there some proof, or rule for these statements to hold true?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can prove them, starting from the definition of *intersection* of sets :

> $x \in A \cap B$ **iff** $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$

and the "basic fact" that *equality* between sets amounts to mutual *inclusion* : $A = B$ **iff** $A \subseteq B$ **and** $B \subseteq A$.

In turn, to prove *inclusion* you have to use its definition :

> $A \subseteq B$ **iff** : if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$.

You can try yourself the above "machinery" proving that :

> > $(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**
$$
A \cap B = B \cap A
$$
so that all three statements are related. Now we can prove the first one (and thus all three) through double inclusion i.e. we prove
$$
(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) \subset A \cap B \cap C \text{ and } (A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) \supset A \cap B \cap C
$$
which shows
$$
(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C
$$
Do you know how to show the above?

**Spoiler:**

> $x \in (A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) \implies x \in A, B, C \implies x \in A \cap B \cap C$. $x \in A \cap B \cap C \implies x \in A,B , x \in B,C \implies x \in (A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)$

Answer (score 2):

$(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap (B \cap B) \cap C  = A \cap B \cap C$, using associativity of $\cap$ (i.e. it doesn't matter where we put brackets), and $B \cap B = B$.

The second on wis similar, but we also use commutativity (the order in $\cap$ does not matter): $(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C) = A \cap B \cap A \cap C = (A \cap A) \cap B \cap C = A \cap B \cap C$.

You probably yes how to do the third one this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

Intersection is both commutative and associative, so we can change the order of your expressions and remove (and add) parenthesis. Doing this for the first expression, we get:
$(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap B \cap C = A \cap (B \cap B) \cap C$.
Now, the intersection of two sets (informally) is the set which has both of the two sets in question. If the two sets are the same, then *every* element in one is in the other, and so the intersection of a set B with itself is B. Thus, $B \cap B = B$.
The expression in question thus simplifies to $A \cap B \cap C$.
A very similar argument can be used to simplify the second expression and the third one.